# problem in scripting

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

when I am executing this on the command line:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}$3~/^353/{print}' axeM10_20110510100219_59.DAT_353 >log
```

it executes vey nicely without taking much time and instantly gives me the output file.

but when I am including this in a shell script :

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

for i in *.DAT_353
do
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}$3~/^353/{print}'  ${i} > ${i}_changed >/dev/null
done

exit
```

the script is generating a 0 byte files.
may I know what is the problem here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `>/dev/null` because that is where your stdout is being redirected to.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Dogbane pointed out,
 `>` redirects the standard output by default. Hence there is no need to forcefully redirect it . Here is a link to more of the redirection tricks[Standard Input and Output Redirection](http://www.lamfa.u-picardie.fr/asch/f/MeCS/courseware/users/help/general/unix/redirection.html)